# GeForce 8400 vga unknown display

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, display-resolution, vga, nvidia-geforce

I'm using ubuntu 16.04 lts with GeForce 8400 GS/PCIe/SSE2 graphic, and i'm using NVIDIA binary driver but in display setting show me unknown display so i can't choose best resolution (1600*900) for my monitor

i used `xrandr` to config it but it doesn't answer

how can i fix this problem? thank you in advance